# How to convert a std::string to in_port_t

Tags: c++

Suppose I have this code:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>

void bark(in_port_t port){
    // etc.
}

int main() {

    const std::string var = "203";
    in_port_t p = var;
    bark(p);

    return 0;
}
```

How would I convert the std::string to an [in_port_t](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/netinetin.h.html)?

Comment: @ross You may try something with a `std::back_inserter` specialized for `in_port_t`.

Comment: No idea if this would answer your question as it's very vague but it seems like you should just parse the strings into a network order `uint16_t` (see [`htons()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htons)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As from the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/netinetin.h.html) you've linked (emphasis mine)

> > ```
> >  in_port_t
> > ```
> >
> > An unsigned integral type of **exactly 16 bits**.

Since `in_port_t` is unsigned, the `std::string` can be passed into the function as an unsigned integer.

You convert it to a number matching for `in_port_t` (e.g. using the `std::stoi()` function and a sanity check for numbers being less/equal than `std::numeric_limits::max<uint16_t>()`), and bang them into network byte order shape (e.g. using `htons()`).

Answer (score 1):

They say that in_port_t is an integral 16 bit type. So you should just use something like stoi() with your strings. Also you can use stringstream for that puprose.

```
string str="10003";
stringstream ss;
ss<<str;
unsigned short target;
ss>>target;
```

Comment: Also note, that `in_port_t` is meant to be presented in network byte order.

Comment: Yeah, htons() then, or write your own function that will convert target value to big-endian notation. You can represent your unsigned short as char array with size 2 and then swap arr[0] and arr[1].